How to programmatically run JUnit Test
I have the following code, and I'm trying to automate the execution of specific test cases under two projects. However, it seems that after execution, most of the test results are erroneous. I suspect this might be due to missing dependencies. Could someone help me inspect and modify it?
public class TestRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestExecutionSummary summary1= runSingleTest("E:\\Tutorial\\proj1\\target\\test-classes","test.CFGTestTest");
        TestExecutionSummary summary2= runSingleTest("E:\\Tutorial\\proj2\\target\\test-classes","test.ConfigTest");
        CompareTestResult(summary1,summary2);
    }

    public  static void CompareTestResult(TestExecutionSummary summary1,TestExecutionSummary summary2){
        System.out.println("\n-----------------Compare Test Result-----------------");
        if(summary1.getTestsSucceededCount()==summary2.getTestsSucceededCount()){
            System.out.println("Test1 and Test2 are the same");
            System.out.println("Passed: "+summary1.getTestsSucceededCount()+" Failed: "+summary1.getTestsFailedCount());
        }else{
            System.out.println("Test1 and Test2 are different");
            System.out.println("Test1: "+"Passed: "+summary1.getTestsSucceededCount()+" Failed: "+summary1.getTestsFailedCount());
            System.out.println("Test2: "+"Passed: "+summary2.getTestsSucceededCount()+" Failed: "+summary2.getTestsFailedCount());
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------\n");
    }

    /**
     * Execute a single test.
     * @param classPath The classpath
     * @param className The class name
     * @throws Exception Exceptions
     */
    private static TestExecutionSummary runSingleTest(String classPath,String className) throws Exception {
        Class<?> testClass = getTestClassFromPath(classPath, className);
        assert testClass != null;
        return runTest(testClass);
    }

    /**
     * Get the test class from the classpath and class name.
     * @param classPath The classpath
     * @param className The class name eg: com.example.Test
     * @return The test class
     * @throws Exception Exceptions
     */
    private static Class<?> getTestClassFromPath(String classPath,String className) throws Exception {
        // Check if the path exists
        File file = new File(classPath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Path does not exist");
            return null;
        }
        URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
        try (URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url})) {
            return classLoader.loadClass(className);
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Class loading failed"+e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception"+e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Run the test.
     * @param testClass The test class
     */
    private static TestExecutionSummary runTest(Class<?> testClass) {
        System.out.println("Running tests for class " + testClass.getName());
        Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create(); // Create a Launcher
        // Create a SummaryGeneratingListener
        SummaryGeneratingListener listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener();

        // Create a LauncherDiscoveryRequest that includes the test class
        LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
                .selectors(selectClass(testClass))
                .build();

        // Register the listener with the Launcher
        launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);
        launcher.execute(request); // Execute the tests

        // Get the execute summary
        return listener.getSummary();
    }
}

Here are the output. Although I got the same test results, there were no dependency errors reported. According to the expected outcome, all five function tests should have passed.
Running tests for class test.CFGTestTest
Running tests for class test.CFGTestTest

-----------------Compare Test Result-----------------
Test1 and Test2 are the same
Passed: 0 Failed: 5
-----------------------------------------------------

And I have already added a series of test-related POM dependencies.

TestExecutionSummary has a printFailuresTo() method. call that and inspect what it writes to the PrintWriter. Add the output to the question if it's still not clear.

Something strange here, also: according to the output, summary1.getTestsSucceededCount() is 0 and summary2.getTestsSucceededCount() is also 0 (ie, they are equal). Yet, the else block in CompareTestResult() was the one executed. Are you sure that you've posted the code that produced the output in your question?

Thank you, Bernie, for answering my question. I have now set up the code locally and would like to proceed to test the differences between the same test case in two different versions of the project, one being the new version and the other the old version. This will facilitate our identification and fixing of vulnerabilities or bugs in the old version.

Add the following dependencies to your project:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Then add tests:
public class FirstUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void whenThis_thenThat() {
        // TODO some logic
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void whenSomething_thenSomething() {
        // TODO some logic
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}

